# REGEX - take anything between delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following text:

```
response={\n  &quot;status&quot; : &quot;ERROR&quot;,\n &quot;message&quot; : &quot;<ERROR Mes$@ge can be anything>&quot;,\n &quot;responseMessage&quot; : &quot;Response&quot;,\n &quot;reason&quot; : &quot;REASON&quot;,\n  }
```

I want to extract this part from the above text -

```
&quot;message&quot; : &quot;<ERROR Mes$@ge can be anything>&quot;
```

Please note - error message can have any chars including special chars.

I have written following regex -

```
\&quot;message\&quot; \: \&quot;.+\&quot;,\\n
```

However, it extracts till the last occurrence of `&quot;,\n`.

I think somehow I should count the occurrences of `&quot;` in the regex.

Need help with the Regex.

Comment: If you don't need regex and are just trying to split it you can do this `string.split(",\n").map(a => {return a.trim()}).filter(a => {return a.includes("&quot;message&quot;")});` which is more human readable. http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/Lqfy9x23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the greedy matcher `.+`, you need to use the non-greedy matcher `.+?`

e.g.

```
\&quot;message\&quot; \: \&quot;.+?\&quot;,\\n
                                  ^
```

Comment: wow you saved my day. thank you.

Comment: @NileshBarai, please accept the answer :-D

Comment: accepted. Stack overflow needs 10 mins to accept an answer after the question is posted. :P

Comment: @NileshBarai I didn't know that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have done.

Used `(|)` as an OR statement to separate `&quot;` and `\n`.

I escaped `\n` with `\\n`

```js
let str = "response={\n  &quot;status&quot; : &quot;ERROR&quot;,\n &quot;message&quot; : &quot;<ERROR Mes$@ge can be anything>&quot;,\n &quot;responseMessage&quot; : &quot;Response&quot;,\n &quot;reason&quot; : &quot;REASON&quot;,\n  }"

let replacedStr = str.replace(/(&quot;|\\n)/g,'"');

console.log(replacedStr);
```